# magento 2 new categroy product missing in category page

Tags: magento2, database, products, product-collection, category-products

I am using magento 2.4.4.p1 upgrade from 2.3 to 2.4.4-p1 i have some products in my site in that few are disabled few are enabled after upgradation i am trying to enable one product it enable but not showing in category page when i open direct URL it showing and search page also it showing.

**status ->  enabled
visibility -> catalog search
qty -10000
instock
assigned to category**
it is simple product
same product if i click duplicate and save it showing in category page but exisitng product when enable it not showing
i did reindex rest and reindex no luck

i tried to debug started list.phtml
getLoadedProductCollection() function to listproduct.php _getProductCollection() in this function print query in that query i am seeing only 2 product but category have 3
below is the query

> SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
> INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1'
> LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))
> LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1  WHERE (e.entity_id IN (23462, 23513)) ORDER BY FIELD(e.entity_id,23462,23513)

i did more in to it **_catalogLayer**  object in this file refers Layer.php printed query in getProductCollection() function i can see only same query with 2 products only
i have checked addIsInStockFilterToCollection() function in Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\status.php file see only

> SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
> INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1'
> LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))
> LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1

this query i want know where the below condition adding

**WHERE (e.entity_id IN (23462, 23513)) ORDER BY FIELD(e.entity_id,23462,23513)**
i check Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php but did not find which function it adding please can any one tell me whic fucntion it adding i will check more in to it

Expected query

> SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
> INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1'
> LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))
> LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 WHERE (e.entity_id IN (23462, 23513,16380)) ORDER BY FIELD(e.entity_id,23462,23513,16380);

Answer (score 0):

About the catalog page issue. Totally get that the products are from Elasticsearch, not MYSQL, and you've done a reindex. Good move!

Consider checking the reindexed docs in Elasticsearch or OpenSearch. If you've got Kibana or an OpenSearch dashboard, that'd be super handy. If not, maybe think about setting up Kibana or Open-search dashboard for easier monitoring.

A cool starting point could be adding a breakpoint in `Magento\Elasticsearch7\SearchAdapter\Adapter::query(RequestInterface $request)` to peek into Elasticsearch requests and responses.

Give it a shot and let me know how it goes. If you need more help, I'm around!

Comment: Distopian Ninja   placed breack point there not adding product ids "e.entity_id IN (23462, 23513,16380))" in that file only showing query with attributes

Comment: i want know Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection.php in this whic fucntion is adding WHERE (e.entity_id IN (23462, 23513,16380)) ORDER BY FIELD(e.entity_id,23462,23513,16380); this where condition